# How to correctly build Jsoup.jar and export it to be used by Android APP

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, jsoup

The current Jsoup release 1.7.3 has a known issue that it is using String.isEmpty() which is not supported by Android API Level 8.

I can see crash report of my app so I tried to fix this by change the source code of Jsoup and build my own jsoup.fix.jar. I test this jar with JAVA application and it worked fine on my PC.

I noticed that when I remove the original jsoup-1.7.3.jar from my project, there is errors complaining cannot find jsoup stuff, and the those errors are gone after I add the jsoup.fix.jar which seems to be good. I also check the JAVA build path and the exporting configurations, jsoup.fix.jar are all set as it should.

However, when I tried to run the APP on my Android devices, the APP crashed and saying it cannot find org.jsoup.Jsoup.

I checked the jsoup.fix.jar, opened it with JD-GUI and find the classes are all there, but I used my dex2jar to convert the classes.dex in my /bin directory, I cannot see nay org.jsoup stuff.

Just replace my jar file with the original jar will not have the same issue reproduced.

I also noticed that in my jar, the MANIFEST.MF file only have one line of content, but in the released jsoup-1.7.3.jar, the MANIFEST.MF contains a lot of content.

I am confused now, questions:

1. Am I doing wrong when build my own jar?
2. Why the APK still cannot include the jsoup pacakage even I configured it to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason might be the jar is exported from a JAVA project.

I have tried to create an Android project and copy the source files into it and then export another jar file, and it works!

Could anybody explain why?